# Scrollable datatable in rowExpansion - Messed up column width

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying to put a scrollable datatable inside of a rowExpansion tag, but the resulting datatable comes out all weird, like this:
[image]

Code:

```
<p:rowExpansion>
<h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4"
             styleClass="ui-widget-content"
             columnClasses="label, value">
    <h:outputText value="Registrerad:"/>
    <h:outputText id="registered" value="#{campaignOfferGroupView.formatDate(offerGroup.registerDate)}"/>

    <h:outputText value="Senast ändrad:"/>
    <h:outputText id="changeDate" value="#{campaignOfferGroupView.formatDate(offerGroup.changeDate)}"/>

    <h:outputText value="Ändrad av:"/>
    <h:outputText id="changedBy" value="#{offerGroup.changedBy}"/>
</h:panelGrid>

<p:dataTable var="campaignCode" value="#{campaignOfferGroupView.getCampaignCodesForGroup(offerGroup.id)}"
             scrollable="true" scrollHeight="120">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Kampanjkoder tillhörande kampanjerbjudandegruppen
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="ID">
        #{campaignCode.id}
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Namn">
        #{campaignCode.description}
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Start">
        #{campaignCode.startDate}
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Stop">
        #{campaignCode.stopDate}
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Anyone have any idea why this is? If I remove the scrollable attribute the table looks fine:
[image]

Incidentally, is there any way to remove the grey empty column created by a scrollable DataTable as seen in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableScrolling.jsf?

EDIT: I have noticed that the ShowCase has column size fixed using the style attribute. I would rather avoid this if possible.